# Aligning Artwork Between Gores and Resolving Vertex Symmetry

Tags: uv, vertices, texture-painting

I am currently working on a real-world application involving the creation of a 10' sphere using Blender. The sphere has been modeled to scale, and I have added seams to create 12 equal gores, along with two tops and bottoms. For texture mapping, I utilized the UV unwrap feature to create a UV map.

[image: Image Texture]

Next, I created a new image texture and colour filled the sphere with a bleed. Using a stencil brush, I applied the artwork to the surface of the sphere. While the model in Blender looks great, I encountered an issue when I exported the UV map & image texture to Illustrator. The artwork does not align properly between the gores, leading to a visible discrepancy.

[image: Artwork Alignment Illustrator]

Upon further inspection in the UV editor, I noticed that the vertices on opposite sides of each gore are not symmetrical. I believe this discrepancy in vertex placement seems to be causing the misalignment of the artwork.

[image: Blender Vertex Alignment]

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue within Blender. Specifically, I am seeking advice on how to ensure proper alignment of the artwork between the gores in the exported UV map. Additionally, I am interested in learning how to achieve vertex symmetry across the gores to address the misalignment issue.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and expertise.